# List View with Section Headings

Tags: android, listview, optimization

I've seen quite a few examples of how to add alphabetical section headers to list views online.  Example:

[image: section headers]

I implemented the functionality from
[this website](http://eshyu.wordpress.com/2010/08/15/cursoradapter-with-alphabet-indexed-section-headers/)
. However, I have a list of approximately 8000 items.  When trying to load this page it takes about 8 seconds which is obviously way too slow.  With just a normal AlphabetIndexer it takes about 1.5 seconds (still slow, but much better).

Does anyone have any ideas on how to speed this up?  If not, are there any other examples that are quicker than this?

Thanks!

Comment: Have a look at this, http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-listview.html , I know its not exactly what you want since you cant use the quick scroll through the letters but it seems to be a lot lighter and tends to load pretty fast

Comment: 1.5 seconds for 8000 items and you think that's slow?

Comment: @SmartLemon  Thanks, but the quick scroll is pretty much essential for this list.

Comment: @MisterSquonk  It can never be fast enough :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What exactly do you mean by trying to load the page? How long does it take if you just load the items and don't do any indexing? 8000 items is not that many to iterate over. It could however be a lot of items to load from disk, or the internet. You might want to consider showing a loading screen and reading in the data for your rows in the background.

The code you showed looks particularly complicated for what you're trying to do. Below is a solution I've used. You can google for SectionIndexer. In my code itemManager is basically just an abstraction on a list, placeholders are null values, everything else is the data structure containing the information for the rows. Some code is omitted:

```
//based on http://twistbyte.com/tutorial/android-listview-with-fast-scroll-and-section-index

private class ContactListAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements SectionIndexer {
    final HashMap<String, Integer> alphaIndexer = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    final HashMap<Integer, String> positionIndexer = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
    String[] sections;

    public ContactListAdapter() {
        setupHeaders();
    }

    public void setupHeaders(){
        itemManager.clearPlaceholders();
        for (int i = 0; i < itemManager.size(); i++) {
            String name = itemManager.get(i).displayName();
            String firstLetter = name.substring(0, 1);
            if (!alphaIndexer.containsKey(firstLetter)) {
                itemManager.putPlaceholder(i);
                alphaIndexer.put(firstLetter, i);
                positionIndexer.put(i, firstLetter);
                ++i;
            }

        }
        final Set<String> sectionLetters = alphaIndexer.keySet();
        final ArrayList<String> sectionList = new ArrayList<String>(sectionLetters);
        Collections.sort(sectionList);
        sections = new String[sectionList.size()];
        sectionList.toArray(sections);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return itemManager.isPlaceholder(position) ? ViewType.HEADER.ordinal() : ViewType.CONTACT.ordinal();
    }

    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {
        return ViewType.values().length;
    }

    @Override
    public int getPositionForSection(int section) {
        return alphaIndexer.get(sections[section]);
    }

    @Override
    public int getSectionForPosition(int position) {
        return 1;
    }

    @Override
    public Object[] getSections() {
        return sections;
    }
```

Comment: I can't, but you shouldn't have too much trouble filling in anything I've omitted. Anything in particular you're having trouble with?

Comment: I'm confused with  itemManager.putPlaceholder(i); itemManager itself is derived from what? Also in getSectionForPosition you just return 1.
Anyways, thanks for response.

Comment: getSectionForPosition doesn't do anything, so you can return whatever you want. itemManager is an abstraction that doesn't matter. just think about itemManager as a list, and putPlaceholder as inserting null in a specific position. isPlaceholder could be list.get(index) == null. Also note that my original code is less than ideal (shouldn't be modifying a list while iterating over it), but once you get the idea it wouldn't be hard to fix.

Answer (score 0):

ListView adapters have a class you can override called [getViewType(int position)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#getItemViewType%28int%29) and [getViewTypeCount()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#getViewTypeCount%28%29).

Those you would override to allow Android to know how many different type of views your adapter uses.

In your case override `getViewTypeCount()` to return 2 since you will have two types of views. One your standard and second your header view.

Than you will need to know at what position you will have your header views shown. Once you do you can easily return your views on the `getView(...)` function.

Comment: That is what the link I provided does.  However, I assume it's the "know at what position you will have your header views shown" which is slowing things down.  That's the part I'm looking at how to speed up but I'm just not sure where to start.

Comment: I would recommend you cache your data inside a SQLite database.  There you can easily and really fast sort and add these header rows.  Than putting that database data to the adapter will be super fast and easy!